# Treeview has an empty column at front

Tags: python, tkinter

In my `Treeview` I see an empty column. I work with `SQLite3` and there is nothing to see there with an empty column.

[Image of what happens here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TBzw.jpg)

(It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.) So useless more tekst here..........

```
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3
from tkinter import messagebox, ttk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from itertools import chain
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

# Maak verbinding met de database
conn = sqlite3.connect('calculatie.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

def create_database():
    # Controleer of de tabel al bestaat
    cursor.execute("PRAGMA table_info(calculatie)"),
    table_info = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.execute("PRAGMA table_info(frezen)"),
    table_frezen = cursor.fetchall()

    if not table_info:
        # Tabel bestaat nog niet, dus maak deze aan
        query = """
        CREATE TABLE calculatie (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            klant TEXT,
            artikelnummer TEXT,
            tekeningnummer TEXT,
            revisie TEXT,
            omschrijving TEXT,
            stuks INTEGER,
            prijs REAL,
            code TEXT,
            Zagen REAL,
            Draaien REAL,
            Frezen REAL,
            Slijpen_1 REAL,
            Slijpen_2 REAL,
            Slijpen_3 REAL,
            Rondslijpen REAL,
            CO_slijpen REAL,
            Draadvonken REAL,
            GM_Engineering REAL,
            material REAL,
            hardening REAL,
            treatment REAL,
            outsource REAL,
            tool_costs REAL,
            transport REAL,
            packaging REAL,
            notes REAL
        )
        """
        cursor.execute(query)
        conn.commit()
        print("Tabel 'calculatie' is aangemaakt.")
    if not table_frezen:
        query = """
        CREATE TABLE frezen (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            program_time REAL,
            setting_time REAL,
            mill_time_1 REAL,
            change_time1 REAL,
            mill_time_2 REAL,
            change_time2 REAL,
            mill_time_3 REAL,
            change_time3 REAL,
            mill_time_4 REAL,
            change_time4 REAL,
            mill_time_5 REAL,
            change_time5 REAL,
            mill_time_6 REAL,
            change_time6 REAL,
            mill_time_7 REAL,
            change_time7 REAL,
            mill_time_8 REAL,
            change_time8 REAL,
            mill_time_9 REAL,
            change_time9 REAL,
            mill_time_10 REAL,
            id_calc INTEGER,
            FOREIGN KEY (id_calc) REFERENCES calculatie(id)
        )
        """
        cursor.execute(query)
        conn.commit()
        print("Tabel 'frezen' is aangemaakt.")
    else:
        print("Tabel 'calculatie' bestaat al. Het aanmaken is overgeslagen.")

    # Sluit de databaseverbinding
    conn.close()

# Search function
def search_record():
    # Connect to database
    conn = sqlite3.connect('calculatie.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    selected_field = search_field_var.get()  # Get the selected field from the dropdown
    search_query = search_entry.get()        # Get the search query from the entry

    if search_query.startswith('*') and search_query.endswith('*'):
        # Both asterisks are present, use LIKE for partial matching
        search_query = search_query.strip('*')
        query = f"SELECT * FROM calculatie WHERE {selected_field} LIKE ?"
        cursor.execute(query, (f"%{search_query}%",))
    else:
        # No asterisks, use = for exact matching
        query = f"SELECT * FROM calculatie WHERE {selected_field} = ?"
        cursor.execute(query, (search_query,))

    data = cursor.fetchall()
    
    # Clear treeview
    for row in tree.get_children():
        tree.delete(row)

    for row in data:
        item_data = {"ID": row[0],
            "Klant": row[1], "Artikelnummer": row[2], "Tekeningnummer": row[3],"Revisie": row[4],"Omschrijving": row[5],
            "Stuks": row[6],"Prijs": row[7],"Code": row[8],"Zagen": row[9],"Draaien": row[10],"Frezen": row[11],
            "Slijpen_1": row[12],"Slijpen_2": row[13],"Slijpen_3": row[14],"Rondslijpen": row[15],"CO_slijpen": row[16],
            "Draadvonken": row[17],"GM_Engineering": row[18],"Materiaal": row[19],"Hardening": row[20],"Treatment": row[21],
            "Outsource": row[22],"Tool_Costs": row[23],"Transport": row[24],"Packaging": row[25],"Notes": row[26]
            }
        tree.insert("", "end", values=list(item_data.values()))

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def clear_search():
    # Connect to database
    conn = sqlite3.connect('calculatie.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # Clear treeview
    for row in tree.get_children():
        tree.delete(row)

    cursor.execute("SELECT * from calculatie")
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    # Insert the data into the treeview
    for row in records:
        item_data = {"ID": row[0],
            "Klant": row[1], "Artikelnummer": row[2], "Tekeningnummer": row[3],"Revisie": row[4],"Omschrijving": row[5],
            "Stuks": row[6],"Prijs": row[7],"Code": row[8],"Zagen": row[9],"Draaien": row[10],"Frezen": row[11],
            "Slijpen_1": row[12],"Slijpen_2": row[13],"Slijpen_3": row[14],"Rondslijpen": row[15],"CO_slijpen": row[16],
            "Draadvonken": row[17],"GM_Engineering": row[18],"Materiaal": row[19],"Hardening": row[20],"Treatment": row[21],
            "Outsource": row[22],"Tool_Costs": row[23],"Transport": row[24],"Packaging": row[25],"Notes": row[26]
            }
        tree.insert("", "end", values=list(item_data.values()))

# Delete selected row
def delete_selection():
    selected_items = tree.selection()
    if not selected_items:
        messagebox.showwarning("Delete", "No record selected.")
        return

    # Establish a connection to the SQLite database
    conn = sqlite3.connect("calculatie.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    query = "DELETE FROM calculatie WHERE id = ?"
    
    if len(selected_items) == 1:
        # Only one record is selected
        if messagebox.askyesno("Delete", "Do you want to delete this record?"):
            # User clicked 'Yes', so proceed with the delete operation
            selected_id = tree.item(selected_items[0])['values'][0]
            if tree.exists(selected_items[0]):
                cursor.execute(query, (selected_id,))
                conn.commit()
                tree.delete(selected_items[0])
                messagebox.showinfo("Delete", "Record is deleted.")
                print("Record is deleted.")
            else:
                print(f"Item {selected_id} not found in the tree.")
    else:
        # Multiple records are selected
        if messagebox.askyesno("Delete", "Do you want to delete these records?"):
            # User clicked 'Yes', so proceed with the delete operation
            for item in selected_items:
                selected_id = tree.item(item)['values'][0]
                if tree.exists(item):
                    cursor.execute(query, (selected_id,))
                    conn.commit()
                    tree.delete(item)
                else:
                    print(f"Item {selected_id} not found in the tree.")
            messagebox.showinfo("Delete", "Records are deleted.")
            print("Records are deleted.")

    # Close the cursor and connection
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

def sort_column(tree, col, reverse):
    # Get all the data in the column to be sorted
    data = [(tree.set(child, col), child) for child in tree.get_children('')]
    # Sort the data in place
    data.sort(reverse=reverse)

    for index, (val, child) in enumerate(data):
        tree.move(child, '', index)

def numeric_sort(value):
    # Custom sorting function for treating values as integers
    try:
        return int(value)
    except ValueError:
        return 0  # Return 0 for non-numeric values

def toggle_topmost(event):
    # Check if the window currently has the focus
    if event.widget == database_window and event.type == "7":  # FocusIn event type
        database_window.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
    else:
        database_window.wm_attributes("-topmost", False)

# Treeview window
def open_database_tree(general_info_entries, bewerkingen_entries, overige_kosten_entries, mill_entry, totaal_kosten_value, textbox):
    global tree, search_entry, item_data, search_field_var, database_window
    conn = sqlite3.connect('calculatie.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    database_window = tk.Toplevel()
    database_window.title("Database")
    database_window.geometry("1440x768")
    database_window.iconbitmap(r"images/pss.ico")
    database_window.minsize(700,350)
    database_window.focus_force()
#    database_window.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
    database_window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    database_window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    # Bind the event handler to the focus events - Needs checking, not working atm
    database_window.bind("<FocusIn>", toggle_topmost)
    database_window.bind("<FocusOut>", toggle_topmost)

    # Frame for buttons
    sd_frame = tk.Frame(database_window, height=40, padx=5, pady=5)
    sd_frame.pack(fill=tk.X)
    sd_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=2)

    # Create the search combobox with the field options
    search_field_var = tk.StringVar()
    search_combobox = ttk.Combobox(sd_frame, textvariable=search_field_var, state='readonly', values=["Klant", "Artikelnummer", "Tekeningnummer", "Omschrijving"])
    search_combobox.set("Klant")  # Set a default value
    search_combobox.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(0,5), sticky="w")

    # Create the search entry and button
    search_entry = tk.Entry(sd_frame, width=30, font=("Segoe UI", 10))
    search_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")
    search_button = tk.Button(sd_frame, text="Search", command=search_record)
    search_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, sticky="w")

    # Remove Record
    delete_button = tk.Button(sd_frame, text="Delete", command=delete_selection)
    delete_button.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=(0,5), sticky="w")

    # Remove Record
    clear_search_button = tk.Button(sd_frame, text="Clear search", command=clear_search)
    clear_search_button.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky="w")

    # Create a frame to hold the Treeview and scrollbar
    frame = tk.Frame(database_window, padx=10)
    frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    frame.rowconfigure(0, pad=10, weight=0)

    tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=["ID", "Klant", "Artikelnummer", "Tekeningnummer", 
                                                  "Revisie", "Omschrijving", "Stuks", "Prijs", "Code",
                                                    "Zagen", "Draaien", "Frezen", "Slijpen_1", "Slijpen_2",
                                                      "Slijpen_3", "Rondslijpen", "CO_slijpen", "Draadvonken",
                                                        "GM_Engineering", "Materiaal", "Hardening", "Treatment",
                                                          "Outsource", "Tool_Costs", "Transport", "Packaging", "Notes"])

    tree.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)


  # Scrollbars
    scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=tree.xview)
    scrollbar.pack(fill=tk.X, side=tk.BOTTOM)
    tree.configure(xscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

    # Fetch data from the database
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM calculatie")
    data = cursor.fetchall()

    heading_mapping = {
    "Revisie": "Rev",
    "Zagen": "Zgn",
    "Draaien": "Dr",
    "Frezen": "Fr",
    "Slijpen_1": "Slp1",
    "Slijpen_2": "Slp2",
    "Slijpen_3": "Slp3",
    "Rondslijpen": "Øslp",
    "CO_slijpen": "CO-Slp",
    "Draadvonken": "Wedm",
    "GM_Engineering": "GM/Eng",
    }
    
    # Add column headings for all columns
    headings = ["ID", "Klant", "Artikelnummer", "Tekeningnummer", "Revisie", "Omschrijving", "Stuks",
                "Prijs", "Code", "Zagen", "Draaien", "Frezen", "Slijpen_1", "Slijpen_2", "Slijpen_3",
                "Rondslijpen", "CO_slijpen", "Draadvonken", "GM_Engineering", "Materiaal", "Hardening",
                "Treatment", "Outsource", "Tool_Costs", "Transport", "Packaging", "Notes"]

    # Insert the data into the treeview
    for row in data:
        item_data = {"ID": row[0],
            "Klant": row[1], "Artikelnummer": row[2], "Tekeningnummer": row[3],"Revisie": row[4],"Omschrijving": row[5],
            "Stuks": row[6],"Prijs": row[7],"Code": row[8],"Zagen": row[9],"Draaien": row[10],"Frezen": row[11],
            "Slijpen_1": row[12],"Slijpen_2": row[13],"Slijpen_3": row[14],"Rondslijpen": row[15],"CO_slijpen": row[16],
            "Draadvonken": row[17],"GM_Engineering": row[18],"Materiaal": row[19],"Hardening": row[20],"Treatment": row[21],
            "Outsource": row[22],"Tool_Costs": row[23],"Transport": row[24],"Packaging": row[25],"Notes": row[26]
        }
        tree.insert("", "end", values=list(item_data.values()))

    # Set column headings for all columns
    column_widths = [20, 50, 110, 125, 30, 200, 25, 80, 90, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 100]
#    max_width = [20, 50, 110, 125, 30, 200, 25, 80, 90, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25]

    for col, heading in enumerate(headings):
        # Use the mapping if available, otherwise use the original heading
        display_heading = heading_mapping.get(heading, heading)
        tree.heading(heading, text=display_heading, command=lambda c=heading: sort_column(tree, c, False))
        tree.column(heading, anchor=tk.CENTER, minwidth=column_widths[col], width=column_widths[col], stretch=False)


    # Bind the set_selected_data function to the Double-1 event
    tree.bind("<Double-1>", lambda event: set_selected_data())
#    tree.bind("<Button-3>", on_right_click)    

    # Calculate column widths based on the data
    for col, heading in enumerate(tree["columns"]):
        max_width = max([tkFont.Font().measure(str(tree.set(child, heading))) for child in tree.get_children()])
        tree.column(heading, width=max_width + 8)  # Add some padding to the calculated width

    # Set the displaycolumns option to show all columns except the last one (Packaging)
    tree["displaycolumns"]

    def set_selected_data():
        global selected_item
        # Get the selected items
        selected_item = tree.selection()
        if selected_item:
            # Get the data of the selected row
            item_data = tree.item(selected_item)["values"]

            # Combine all the entry dictionaries into a single iterable
            all_entries = chain(general_info_entries.values(), bewerkingen_entries.values(), overige_kosten_entries.values())
            # Loop through all the entries and make them empty
            for entry in all_entries:
                entry.delete(0, tk.END)
                mill_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
                totaal_kosten_value.delete(0, tk.END)

            # Fill in entry fields
            general_info_entries["Klant"].insert(0, item_data[1])
            general_info_entries["Artikelnummer"].insert(0, item_data[2])
            general_info_entries["Tekeningnummer"].insert(0, item_data[3])
            general_info_entries["Revisie"].insert(0, item_data[4])
            general_info_entries["Omschrijving"].insert(0, item_data[5])
            general_info_entries["Aantal stuks"].insert(0, item_data[6])
            totaal_kosten_value.insert(0, item_data[7])
            general_info_entries["Code"].insert(0, item_data[8])
            bewerkingen_entries["Zagen"].insert(0, item_data[9])
            bewerkingen_entries["Draaien"].insert(0, item_data[10])
            mill_entry.insert(0, item_data[11])
            bewerkingen_entries["Slijpen 1"].insert(0, item_data[12])
            bewerkingen_entries["Slijpen 2"].insert(0, item_data[13])
            bewerkingen_entries["Slijpen 3"].insert(0, item_data[14])
            bewerkingen_entries["Rondslijpen"].insert(0, item_data[15])
            bewerkingen_entries["CO-slijpen"].insert(0, item_data[16])
            bewerkingen_entries["Draadvonken"].insert(0, item_data[17])
            bewerkingen_entries["GM/Engineering"].insert(0, item_data[18])
            overige_kosten_entries["Materiaal p/s"].insert(0, item_data[19])
            overige_kosten_entries["Harden Totaal"].insert(0, item_data[20])
            overige_kosten_entries["Behandelingen totaal"].insert(0, item_data[21])
            overige_kosten_entries["Uitbestedingen totaal"].insert(0, item_data[22])
            overige_kosten_entries["Gereedschapskosten"].insert(0, item_data[23])
            overige_kosten_entries["Transportkosten"].insert(0, item_data[24])
            overige_kosten_entries["Verpakkingskosten"].insert(0, item_data[25])
            textbox.insert(0, item_data[26])
```

I checked everything but i couldn't find the problem.

Comment: Please try to reduce the amount of code that is in your question instead of adding useless text. If the question is about the appearance of the tree, we don't need any of the database code or any widgets other than the treeview and enough other code to make it run. You posted nearly 400 lines of code and when we run it it doesn't produce a tree widget. See [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the column for the tree (hierarchy of nodes). That column can be represented with the special column identifier `"#0"`, and  you can hide it by setting the `show` option to `"headings"` (by default it's `"tree headings"`).

```
tree.configure(show="headings")
```